# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined when using async/await and javascript class?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am new to javascript classes, and await/async, and can't see why I get an error when trying to call the `dateFromNowInMinutes` in the `GoogleCalendar.js` class below.

```
// THIS IS WHAT FAILS WHEN I TRY AND CALL IT
var timeMax = this.dateFromNowInMinutes(60);
```

and this is the error I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dateFromNowInMinutes')
```

I feel it's something to do with how I'm using `this` in my class, possibly in the `getEvents` method, but am not sure.

Here's how I am calling it

#### demo.js

```
var GoogleCalendar = require('./GoogleCalendar');
var gcal = new GoogleCalendar();

async function main(){
  let events = await gcal.getEvents();
  if (events.length > 0)
  {
    console.log(events[0]);
  }
}

main().catch(console.log);
```

and then when I run it, I get the following

```
$ node demo.js
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dateFromNowInMinutes')
    at listEvents (/Users/bparks/example/node/test/GoogleCalendar.js:73:24)
    at async GoogleCalendar.getEvents (/Users/bparks/example/node/test/GoogleCalendar.js:13:12)
    at async main (/Users/bparks/example/node/test/demo.js:5:16)
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at main (/Users/bparks/example/node/test/demo.js:6:14)
```

Here is the GoogleCalendar.js class, mostly taken from [a Google calendar quick start](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/nodejs) which I am attempting to put into a javascript class with some slight modifications.

##### GoogleCalendar.js

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');
const process = require('process');
const { authenticate } = require('@google-cloud/local-auth');
const { google } = require('googleapis');

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'];
const TOKEN_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'token.json');
const CREDENTIALS_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'credentials.json');

class GoogleCalendar {
  async getEvents() {
    return await this.authorize().then(this.listEvents).catch(console.error);
  }

  async loadSavedCredentialsIfExist() {
    try {
      const content = await fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH);
      const credentials = JSON.parse(content);
      return google.auth.fromJSON(credentials);
    } catch (err) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  async saveCredentials(client) {
    const content = await fs.readFile(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
    const keys = JSON.parse(content);
    const key = keys.installed || keys.web;
    const payload = JSON.stringify({
      type: 'authorized_user',
      client_id: key.client_id,
      client_secret: key.client_secret,
      refresh_token: client.credentials.refresh_token,
    });
    await fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, payload);
  }

  async authorize() {
    let client = await this.loadSavedCredentialsIfExist();
    if (client) {
      return client;
    }
    client = await authenticate({
      scopes: SCOPES,
      keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
    });
    if (client.credentials) {
      await saveCredentials(client);
    }
    return client;
  }

  dateFromNowInMinutes(minutes){
    var result = new Date();
    result.setTime(result.getTime() + (minutes*60*60*1000));
    return result;
  }

  async listEvents(auth) {
    const calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3', auth });
    var moment = require('moment');

    var timeMin = new Date().toISOString();

    // ###########################################
    // THIS IS WHAT FAILS WHEN I TRY AND CALL IT
    // ###########################################
    var timeMax = this.dateFromNowInMinutes(60);

    var timeMaxS = timeMax.toISOString();
    var iso = timeMax.toISOString();

    const res = await calendar.events.list({
      calendarId: 'primary',
      timeMin: timeMin,
      timeMax: timeMaxS,
      maxResults: 10,
      singleEvents: true,
      orderBy: 'startTime',
    });
    const events = res.data.items;
    if (!events || events.length === 0) {
      // No upcoming events found.
      return [];
    }

    // We have some upcoming events
    var result = events.map((event, i) => {
      const start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
      var item = `${start} - ${event.summary}`;
      return item;
    });
    return result;
  }

}

module.exports = GoogleCalendar;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from this line:

```
    return await this.authorize().then(this.listEvents).catch(console.error);
```

Doing `.then(this.listEvents)` sets the callback to a function pointer, where `this` is not bound to an instance i.e. `this.dateFromNowInMinutes(60);` resolves to `undefined.dateFromNowInMinutes(60)`, which gets you the error.

To fix it, you can either bind to `this` manually:

```
.then(this.listEvents.bind(this))
```

or use an arrow function:

```
.then((auth) => this.listEvents(auth))
```

As @DarrylNoakes pointed out, using an arrow function is usually preferred, as it reads better and avoids some pitfalls, particularly when your function takes arguments.

Comment: Preferably _always_ use a wrapping arrow function for callbacks (unless you have a dedicated callback function), to ensure proper behavior. Try `["1", "2", "3"].map(parseInt)` vs `["1", "2", "3"].map((v) => parseInt(v))`.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes Oh, good point, thank you! Added a note to the answer.